# Error running Symfony 1.4 propel app under docker

Tags: docker, symfony-1.4, propel

I try to run my old Symfony 1.4 propel app under docker and for this I have in my docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    web:
        container_name: Demo_Ads_web

        build:
            context: ./web
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.yml

        environment:
            - APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}

        ports:
            - 8090:80
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}


    db:
        container_name: Demo_Ads_db
        image: mysql:5.6.46
        restart: always
        environment: 
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql


    phpmyadmin:
        container_name: Demo_Ads_phpmyadmin
        depends_on:
          - db
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        ports:
          - 8091:80
        environment:
          PMA_HOST: db
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
```

I am not sure which is valid format for /config/databases.yml, as I need to set db container in it.
I tried it as :

```
all:
  propel:
    class:          sfPropelDatabase
    param:
      dsn:          mysql://root:db@1/Demo_Ads_Docker
```

where Demo_Ads_Docker is db name
1 - password
db - database container 
root logged user

But looks like that is invalid, as I got error :

```
[PropelException]
[wrapped: mysql extension not loaded [User Info: Array]]
```

Which is valid format? Is it error because of wrong params in databases.yml ?

**MODIFIED :**

in my web/Dockerfile.yml mysql is set:

```
FROM php:5.4-apache

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    nano \
    git-core \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    openssl \
    libssl-dev \
    libldap2-dev \
    netcat \
    sqlite3 \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git \
    && cd node \
    && git checkout v12.0.0 \
    && ./configure \
     && make \
     && make install

  RUN npm install cross-env

  RUN  docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-webp-dir=/usr/include/  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/


  RUN  docker-php-ext-install gd  mysql zip bcmath pcntl sysvmsg exif \
&& a2enmod rewrite

COPY virtualhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

do I need mysqli? also please which is format of  /config/databases.yml file with container set ?

**MODIFIED 2 :**
I added both mysql, mysqli, but now running app I got error :

```
[wrapped: connect failed [Native Error: Invalid argument] [User Info: Array]]
```

Is it invalid format of /config/databases.yml file ?

**MODIFIED 3 :**
I remade Demo_Ads/config/databases.yml :

```
all:
  propel:
    class:          sfPropelDatabase
    param:

      classname:  PropelPDO
      dsn:        mysql:dbname=Demo_Ads_db;host=db
      username:   root
      password:   1
```

and create Demo_Ads_db database in phpmyadmin.

I removed cache dir

But running  the app I got error :

```
[wrapped: connect failed [Native Error: No such file or directory] [User Info: Array]]
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Can you show your Dockerfile for your web container ? From the message above it looks like php does not have mysql(i) extension installed.

Comment: pls, look MODIFIED

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED 2

Comment: The extension looks ok now. Seems you now need to read the [symfony 1.4 db configuration doc](https://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/07-Databases) to fix your `database.yml`.

Comment: What did you do to try to fix this last problem ? Where did you look ? What did you research ? Which documentation did your read ? Did you debug anything from your app to try to understand what is happening ? Do you have any idea of the file that is not found ? Do you have any idea of which component is firing this error ?

Comment: I read link to https://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/07-Databases
I am not sure which parameters have I use use. Please example with docker db component connection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid format of db connection is :

```
dsn:          mysql://root:1@db/Demo_Ads_Docker
```

and that works for me!